# I want to delete selected user on Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to delete selected user on Firebase Auth.

Present , i can delete the data of the currently selected user through the database . But I also want to delete the user from the Auth section. I could do this before using the adapter. But I couldn't do that when using Adapter.

My AdminPanel Adapter :

```
package com.example.yagoozonfirebasejava;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.List;

public class AdminPanelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdminPanelAdapter.CardDesingHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Users> usersList;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;



    // Constructor
    public AdminPanelAdapter(Context mContext, List<Users> kisilerListe, DatabaseReference myRef) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.usersList = kisilerListe;
        this.myRef = myRef;
    }
    // Holder class
    public class CardDesingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView usernameAdmin;
        private TextView user_surnameAdminAdapter;
        private TextView user_emailAdminAdapter;
        private TextView user_RealnameeAdminAdapter;
        private TextView userUuidAdmin;
        private ImageView deleteUserAdmin;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuthAmdin;

        public CardDesingHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            usernameAdmin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_AdminCard);
            user_RealnameeAdminAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userRealNameAdminCard);
            user_surnameAdminAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userSurnameAdminCard);
            user_emailAdminAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userEmail_AdminCard);
            userUuidAdmin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userUuidAdmin);
            deleteUserAdmin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDeleteUser);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CardDesingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.admin_usercard, viewGroup, false);
        return new CardDesingHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CardDesingHolder cardDesingHolder, int position) {
        final Users user = usersList.get(position);

        cardDesingHolder.user_emailAdminAdapter.setText("Mail : " + user.getUser_email());
        cardDesingHolder.user_surnameAdminAdapter.setText("Surname : " + user.getUser_surname());
        cardDesingHolder.user_RealnameeAdminAdapter.setText("Name : " + user.getUser_name());
        cardDesingHolder.usernameAdmin.setText("Username : " + user.getUser_username());
        cardDesingHolder.userUuidAdmin.setText("User UUID : " + user.getUser_id());

        // User Delete
        cardDesingHolder.deleteUserAdmin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

                alert.setTitle("Alert!");
                alert.setMessage("Are you sure??");

                alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Delete User value's on Database
                        myRef.child(user.getUser_id()).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "User Successfully Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                alert.create().show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usersList.size();
    }
}
```

My Admin Panel Class :

```
package com.example.yagoozonfirebasejava;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.view.View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER;

public class AdminPanel extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbarAdmin;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewAdminPanel;
    private ArrayList<Users> usersArrayList;
    private AdminPanelAdapter adapter;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuthAdmin;
    private Button btn_menu;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_panel);
        /*
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminPanel.this, ProfilePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } else {
            // No user is signed in
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminPanel.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }*/


        // Firebase Auth
        mAuthAdmin = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        // Toolbar Settings //
        toolbarAdmin = findViewById(R.id.toolbarAdmin);
        toolbarAdmin.setTitle("Yagoozon - Admin Panel");
        toolbarAdmin.setSubtitle("Welcome Admin");
        // Menu
        toolbarAdmin.inflateMenu(R.menu.logout_menu);
        toolbarAdmin.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                String mesaj = "";
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.logout_menuid:
                        mAuthAdmin.signOut();
                        Intent out = new Intent(AdminPanel.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(out);
                        finish();
                        mesaj = "User Sign out!";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(AdminPanel.this, mesaj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        // Toolbar Settings End  //

        // Menu Button //
        btn_menu = findViewById(R.id.btn_filterAdminPanel);
        btn_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(AdminPanel.this, btn_menu);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());


                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.filterDate:
                                Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                        .orderByChild("user_email")
                                        .equalTo(mAuthAdmin.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

                                query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        usersArrayList.clear();

                                        for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            Users user = d.getValue(Users.class);
                                            user.setUser_id(d.getKey());

                                            usersArrayList.add(user);

                                        }

                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });

                            return true;

                            case R.id.filterUuid:
                                Query queryUuid = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                        .orderByChild("user_id")
                                        .equalTo(mAuthAdmin.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                                queryUuid.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        usersArrayList.clear();

                                        for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            Users user = d.getValue(Users.class);
                                            user.setUser_id(d.getKey());

                                            usersArrayList.add(user);

                                        }

                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });
                                return true;

                            case R.id.filterDefault:
                                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                        usersArrayList.clear();

                                        for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            Users user = d.getValue(Users.class);
                                            user.setUser_id(d.getKey());

                                            usersArrayList.add(user);

                                        }

                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;

                        }
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });


        // Menu Button End //

        // Definitions
        recyclerViewAdminPanel = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewAdminPanel);

        // Firebase Database Connection
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("Users");


        // Recycler View
        recyclerViewAdminPanel.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewAdminPanel.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // Create Array List
        usersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Recycler View Adapter
        adapter = new AdminPanelAdapter(AdminPanel.this, usersArrayList, myRef);
        recyclerViewAdminPanel.setAdapter(adapter);

        getUsersAdmin();

    }

    // Get Users Method
    public void getUsersAdmin() {

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                usersArrayList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Users user = d.getValue(Users.class);
                    user.setUser_id(d.getKey());

                    usersArrayList.add(user);

                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    // Back Button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finishAffinity(); // or finish();
    }
}
```

My App Delete Screen Screen Shot :

[image]

Click on the trash icon below , which you user want to delete. Deletes that user from the database. But it doesn't delete on Auth .

I tried a few different ways, but I couldn't. I want to delete the selected user data from database while deleting from Auth.

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I guess you didn't read what I wrote or I couldn't wrote. This code only deletes user data from the database. I want to delete users from the auth part.

Comment: You can't delete arbitrary users from client code.  That would be a security hole.  You will need to write backend code to delete any user using the Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: @DougStevenson Normally I could erase directly with a single line of code. But I use adapter and holder.I couldn't delete it using some kind of adapter.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with adapters or holders.  You just can't delete any Firebase Auth user account using client code.

Comment: @DougStevenson  I configure my button codes and users with the adapter. So I'm trying to delete it over the adapter. Can I delete a user from the adapter via the normal client? How do I delete it if I can delete it?

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me in deleting a user account.

**For Facebook**

```
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        try {
            AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderId());
            if (user != null) {
                user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Log.d("Tag", "User account deleted.");
                                                    fbLogut();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                            }
                        });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**For Google**

```
try {
            AuthCredential credentialg = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), null);
            // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
            if (user != null) {
                user.reauthenticate(credentialg)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                user.delete()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Log.d("Tag", "User account deleted.");
                                                    googleSignout();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                            }
                        });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**For E-mail Auth:**

```
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
                    .getCredential(em, password);
            if (user != null) {
                user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(task -> user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                                    if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Log.d("Tag", "User account deleted.");
                                    }
                                }));
            }
```

or(If you are an admin)

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUser(uid);
```

Comment: Where do you get em and password variables and where do you define them?

And i get a error for reauthenticate and delete part.

Comment: em and password are email and passwords of the user. if that doesn't help, check my edited answer.

Comment: I bought em and password now. But i get a error for reauthenticate and delete part.

The solution in your edited answer is such an error. : http://prntscr.com/oli794

Comment: You must install the admin SDK in your project. Add                        
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.9.0' in your Gradle. Documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: I still can't figure it out.

Comment: I tried such a code, but it only deletes the login user.
Code : http://prntscr.com/opyas5

And that's a problem when I try the other single line of code.
Code : http://prntscr.com/opybd5